# Can I change the order of the output fields from the Linux cut command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, cut

I am using cut command in command line and seems I can't get the output I like. 
Do you have any idea why I am getting this? Is it something that I do wrong?

This is the normal output and I would like to output in different order:

```
[root@upbvm500 root]# ls -al IDS_DIR/a | tr -s " "
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 1 17:18 IDS_DIR/a
[root@upbvm500 root]#

[root@upbvm500 root]# ls -al IDS_DIR/a | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f5,6,7,8,3,4,1
-rw-r--r-- root root 0 Jan 1 17:18
```

But as you can see, this is not working like expected.
Any idea why they are switching places?

Comment: Guessing that you want to change the order of the fields, you might want to use any number of other tools, like sed.  Using sed, you can write a substitution command to solve this.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do, but I dont know why this is not working with cut.

Comment: According to the man page, cut doesn't do that.

Comment: do not parse the output of `ls`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From `man cut`:

> Selected input is written in the same order that it is read, and is written exactly once.

Use `awk '{print $5,$6,$7,$8,$3,$4,$1}'` instead of `cut`.

Comment: Of course that won't work if some filename has one or more space(s) in it...

Comment: @MatsPetersson yes, good point but neither would `cut`!

Answer (score 6):

`cut` does not reorder its output. It simply collects a list of which columns to print, then prints them out as they arrive.

Use a different tool such as Awk to reorder output columns.

However, in this patricular case, try with `stat` or `find` instead of `ls`. It is generally not recommended to try to parse the output from `ls`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned, don't parse ls. If you want file information, use [`stat`](http://man.cx/stat)

```
stat -c "%s %y %U %G %A %n" filename
```

You may need to do some extra work to get the timestamp formatted as you want.

```
$ ls -l data
-rw-r--r-- 1 glennj glennj 13 2013-01-01 11:19 data
$ LC_TIME=POSIX ls -l data
-rw-r--r-- 1 glennj glennj 13 Jan  1 11:19 data

$ stat -c "%s %y %U %G %A %n" data 
13 2013-01-01 11:19:53.670015242 -0500 glennj glennj -rw-r--r-- data
$ stat -c "%s %Y %U %G %A %n" data | awk '{$2 = strftime("%b %e %H:%M", $2)} 1'
13 Jan  1 11:19 glennj glennj -rw-r--r-- data
```